# I'm trying to aggregate a measure in Power BI Report Builder and getting nowhere

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am working on a sample project in Power BI Report Builder. *(I couldn't tag it as such because apparently I'm not allowed to create my own tags on this website.)* The measure I am going for in my data cube is called Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_of_Year, but we will call it "Deductible" because that's too long a name to type out every time. I am trying to divide it up by the fields of State, City, and Year.

[image: Here is a picture of the report in design view.]

The Category column tells you whether each row is for a state or a city within that state. The Year and Location columns tell you the year and location that the row is telling you about. The Deductible column shows that measure. The Pct% column formula is Deductible - Total. (I added the Total column because I was having trouble with the Pct% column and wanted to know what was going on.)

Here's where the problem begins.

- The Total column is supposed to tell me what the total deductible is for that specific year. But instead, it just gives me the grand total for all years in the cube. I've run the report enough times to know that this number is $99,669.71.

Here is the formula I am using for the Total column:

```
=round(Sum(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value),2)
```

*The Pct% column is giving me wrong answers too, but it is based on the Total column, so fixing the Total column should also fix the Pct% column.*

- And the data bar is supposed to show me what percent of the total for that year is in that state's row, or what percent of the total for that state is in that city's row. Instead it gives me an error message saying I am missing a closing parenthesis ')' somewhere:

> The Maximum expression for the chart 'DataBar2' contains an error: [BC30198] ')' expected.

Here is the code I used:

```
=(Sum(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value) / (Sum(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value), "StateDS"))
```

As you can see, all three sets of parentheses are opened and closed.

I did figure out that if I move all the parentheses to the end, like so:

```
 =(Sum(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value) / (Sum(Fields!Direct_Claim_Deductible_Recoverable_End_Of_Year.Value, "StateDS")))
```

I resolve that error message but get a different one:

> The ValueAxis_Primary.Maximum expression for the chart 'DataBar2' has a nested aggregate that specifies a dataset scope.  Inner aggregates cannot specify a dataset scope.

It seems to be telling me that I cannot have the denominator of the fraction for the City data bar specify that its scope is the dataset "StateDS", which is the dataset that aggregates by State alone. But I am confused. I don't understand why that would be. And I don't understand what I need to do to make it aggregate by state anyway.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that a Tablix, or just a bunch of text boxes?  What does the Dataset look liks?

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, I am using a Tablix.